# jquery multi step form validation

Tags: jquery, validation, client-side-validation

I need to validate a multi-step form. Are there any decent plugins for doing this?

For example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#MoveStep1').click(function() {
        $("#step1").validate();
    });
});
```

`#step1` is a field set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only suggesting this if you're okay with a quick hack in 4 lines

```
//untested but you'll get the gist, you may need a slight variation on this
$("#step1").wrap('<form id="tmp-form"></form>');
$("#tmp-form").validate();
$("#step1").insertBefore("#tmp-form");
$("#tmp-form").remove();
```

The basic idea is to wrap it in a temporary form. Validate. Remove. Repeat.

```
Benefits:  
use a validation plugin you already know and is well-tested. 
you don't need to change any existing validation rules

Cons:
possible undesired layout effects depending on you style markup
maybe others? once again, not tested just a quick thought
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
//setup validation, don't validate if the control is: ignored, inside an ignored container, or hidden
$("form").validate({ ignore: ".ignore, .ignore *, :hidden" });

$("#MoveStep1").click(function() {
    //assuming each step is in a container with the class Step
    $(".Steps:not(#step1)").addClass(.ignore);
    $("form").valid();
    $(".Steps").removeClass(.ignore);
});
```